# Connecting to Sharepoint REST API with Python

Tags: python, sharepoint

I am trying to connect to sharepoint, via an app, with python, using the following code -

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

site_url = 'https://redacted-admin.sharepoint.com/sites/Test'

app_principal = {
    'client_id': 'redacted',
    'client_secret': 'redacted',
}

context_auth = AuthenticationContext(url=site_url)
context_auth.acquire_token_for_app(client_id=app_principal['client_id'], client_secret=app_principal['client_secret'])

ctx = ClientContext(site_url, context_auth)
web = ctx.web
ctx.load(web)
ctx.execute_query()
print("Web site title: {0}".format(web.properties['Title']))
```

this gives me the following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Sharepoint.py", line 17, in <module>
    ctx.execute_query()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\office365\sharepoint\client_context.py", line 43, in execute_query
    super(ClientContext, self).execute_query()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\client_runtime_context.py", line 37, in execute_query
    self.pending_request.execute_query()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\client_request.py", line 32, in execute_query
    response = self.execute_request_direct(request)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\client_request.py", line 41, in execute_request_direct
    self.context.authenticate_request(request_options)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\client_runtime_context.py", line 15, in authenticate_request
    self.__auth_context.authenticate_request(request)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\auth\authentication_context.py", line 37, in authenticate_request
    request_options.set_header('Authorization', self.provider.get_authorization_header())
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\auth\acs_token_provider.py", line 76, in get_authorization_header
    return 'Bearer {0}'.format(self.access_token["access_token"])
KeyError: 'access_token'
```

I would just like to check that the connection is working before I do anything with it, can anyone help?

Comment: Is the site url correct? it seems that 'redacted-admin.sharepoint.com' is the SP admin center.

Answer (score 0):

From the [DOCS](https://pypi.org/project/Office365-REST-Python-Client/) you should try making the request like this (assuming client_id, and client_sercret) are you username/password and not some other id and token returned from an authentication endpoint.

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

url = site_url = 'https://redacted-admin.sharepoint.com/sites/Test'

app_principal = {
    'client_id': 'redacted',
    'client_secret': 'redacted',
}

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(app_principal['client_id'], app_principal['client_secret']):
  ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
  web = ctx.web
  ctx.load(web)
  ctx.execute_query()
  print "Web title: {0}".format(web.properties['Title'])

else:
  print ctx_auth.get_last_error()
```

Comment: client_id and client_secret are derived from the app on azure in order to circumvent 2 factor authentication. Are you saying this isn't needed?

Comment: The acquire_token_for_user method requires a username and password (according to the docs).  I'm saying, you need to make sure that's what you're passing in, and not some other values.

Comment: Oh okay. Sounds like I still have no idea how to access the API then.